# Can I do any for loop in Lucene query syntax in Azure search?

Tags: loops, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

In azure search , to search by a word /text in multiple fields at the same time this is how my syntax looks like -

```
&queryType=full&search=((name:john) || (firstname:john) || (lastname:john) || (middlename:john))
```

Just wondering if there's any syntax exists like for loop/foreach instead of repeating the search string several times.

imaginary syntax:

```
&queryType=full&search=(name|| firstname || lastname || middlenamejohn): john
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is not possible, howerver, in Azure Search your search query is executed against all searchable fields, unless you set the [searchFields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) parameter. 
If you want to search over all searchable fields, your query could simply looks like this:

```
GET https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]/docs?search=john
```

If the fields in your example are not the only searchable fields and you want you search query to be scoped to them only, use the searchFields parameter:

```
GET https://[service name].search.windows.net/indexes/[index name]/docs?search=john&searchFields=name,firstname,lastname,middlename
```

Let me know if that helps